# Определение конца асинхронной загрузки изображения при отображении динамической картинки ожидания .gif

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть коллекция адресов картинок, расположенных на диске, которая загружается асинхронно при загрузки страницы. Привязка к картинкам осуществляется непосредственно по их адресу и нужно задать значение по умолчанию (у меня картинка с анимацией `gif`, наследуемая от класса `Image`), но для того, чтобы понять когда надо прекратить показывать аннимированную картинку gif по умолчанию нужно определить для этого событие, на которое бы срабатывал триггер. Я попробовал подписаться на событие `Loaded`, но оно срабатывает намного раньше загрузки самой страницы, свойство `TargetNullValue` так же в этом случае не срабатывает по видимому по той же причине.

Вот код WPF:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentPhoneMedias}" >
   <ItemsControl.Resources>
       <gif:AnimatedGIFViewer x:Key="DefaultImageSource" GifSource="default.gif"/>
   </ItemsControl.Resources>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <UniformGrid Columns="5" Rows="6" />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Control Grid.Row="0">
             <Control.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                   <Grid>
                      <Image x:Name="MediaImage" Source="{Binding Path=Path, IsAsync=True}" Loaded="MediaImage_Loaded"/>
                      </Image>
                      <gif:AnimatedGIFViewer x:Name="GIFImage" GifSource="default.gif" />
                   </Grid>
                   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger SourceName="SelectedMediaImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                           <Setter TargetName="GIFImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                       </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Control.Template>
             </Control>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Код C#:

```css
private void MediaImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Image).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Класс динамического изображения "По умолчанию", C# (скачано с Интернета):

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace SAGAInsta.GifAnimation
{
    public class AnimatedGIFViewer : System.Windows.Controls.Image
    {
        GifBitmapDecoder _gf;
        Int32Animation _anim;
        bool _animationIsWorking = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Индес отображаемого кадра GIF-а.
        /// </summary>
        public int FrameIndex
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(FrameIndexProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FrameIndexProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Свойство зависимоти - индес отображаемого кадра GIF-а.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FrameIndexProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FrameIndex", typeof(int), typeof(AnimatedGIFViewer), new UIPropertyMetadata(0, ChangingFrameIndex));

        private Uri _gifSource;
        private double _framesPerSecond = 10.0;

        static void ChangingFrameIndex(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs ev)
        {
            var ob = (AnimatedGIFViewer)obj;
            ob.Source = ob._gf.Frames[(int)ev.NewValue];

            ob.InvalidateVisual();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Адрес отображаемого GIF-а.
        /// </summary>
        public Uri GifSource
        {
            get { return _gifSource; }
            set
            {
                _gifSource = value;
                RefreshGif();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Скорость анимации GIF-а (кадров в секунду) 
        /// </summary>
        public double FramesPerSecond
        {
            get { return _framesPerSecond; }
            set
            {
                _framesPerSecond = value;
                RefreshGif();
            }
        }

        private void RefreshGif()
        {
            if (_gifSource == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(_gifSource.ToString())) return;
            _gf = new GifBitmapDecoder(_gifSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            if (_gf.Frames != null)
            {
                _anim = new Int32Animation(0,
                    _gf.Frames.Count - 1,
                    new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_gf.Frames.Count / FramesPerSecond)));
                _anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                Source = _gf.Frames[0];
            }
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);
            if (!_animationIsWorking && _anim != null)
            {
                BeginAnimation(FrameIndexProperty, _anim);
                _animationIsWorking = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте проще: используйте `PriorityBinding`.

Вот вам пример:

VM:

```
class VM
{
    static Uri imageUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png");
    Lazy<ImageSource> image = new Lazy<ImageSource>(() => LoadImage(imageUri));

    public ImageSource LazyLoadedImage => image.Value;

    static ImageSource LoadImage(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cl = new WebClient())
                cl.OpenRead(imageUri).CopyTo(ms);
            var bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();
            bi.Freeze();
            return bi;
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь картинка будет загружена по запросу, так что первое обращение будет медленным.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="PriorityBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Priority Binding test" Height="250" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- эта маленькая картинка лежит в ресурсах, так что грузится быстро -->
        <BitmapImage UriSource="LoadingGray.png" x:Key="Loading"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Stretch="None">
            <Image.Source>
                <PriorityBinding>
                    <!-- это свойство главнее, поэтому оно первое
                         поскольку загрузка медленная, грузим в фоновом потоке (IsAsync) -->
                    <Binding IsAsync="True" Path="LazyLoadedImage"/>
                    <!-- а это заглушка по умолчанию, будет показываться,
                         пока не загрузится главная картинка -->
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Loading}"/>
                </PriorityBinding>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Для тестирования, вот вам `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new VM();
    }
}
```

(Понятно, в реальном приложении окно не будет само создавать себе VM.)

Получаем: сначала

[image: загрузка...]

и через пол-секунды

[image: загрузилось!]

---

Обновление: Для случая, когда реально нужно две картинки, можно пойти другим путём. Например, можно скрывать первую картинку, когда ширина второй будет больше нуля:

```
<Window x:Class="PriorityBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Priority Binding test" Height="250" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- эта маленькая картинка лежит в ресурсах, так что грузится быстро -->
        <BitmapImage UriSource="LoadingGray.png" x:Key="Loading"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding LazyLoadedImage, IsAsync=True}" Stretch="None"
               Name="MainImage"/>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource Loading}">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <sys:Double x:Key="Zero">0</sys:Double>
                    </Style.Resources>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainImage}"
                                    Value="{StaticResource Zero}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Ну или в вашем случае вместо второго `Image` будет `gif:AnimatedGIFViewer`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, а можно, что-нибудь сделать для триггера, т .к. у меня динамическое изображение показывающееся по умолчанию, и я его я показываю поверх изображения Image (оно только наследуется от Image, но само  не является Image, поэтому не видно)?

Comment: @A.Mikhail: Не совсем понял вопрос — может быть, допишите обновление к вопросу сверху, с кодом?

Comment: Вот я изменил немного свой прежний вопрос.

Comment: @A.Mikhail: Обновил ответ, пробуйте.